# Testing Relationships surrounding Social Media Engagement

Tags: categorical-data, binary-data, count-data, continuous-data, contingency-tables

I'm sure I have a very easy question I'm trying to answer, but as a qualitative researcher who has found themselves trying to help an undergraduate on a quantitative project, I need some help. I'm trying to determine if there are relationships between social media post engagement (number of comments) and the following:

1. Day of the week of the social media post (seven categorical options)
2. Use of a specific word in the social media post (binary yes/no data).

What statistics should I run to investigate these relationships?

Comment: Are the social media posts classified in different categories? Maybe you could describe the data better. But, number of comments is a count, so maybe some count data regression, so search this site for Poisson regression

Comment: Welcome to the site! A good way to get started might be to take the square root of the social media post engagements, and use that "transformed variable" as the response for an ANOVA analysis with Day of Week and Post Uses Special Word as predictors. Are you familiar with ANOVAs?